Table problem overleaf
This is driving me crazy. Any suggestion?
The cell is just partially colored.
\begin{table}[H]
\centering 
\scriptsize % Reduced font size
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|X|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{bluepoli!40} % Header row
    \makecell{\textbf{U} \\ \textbf{[\textit{m}/\textit{s}]}} & 
    \textbf{Re} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{T}$_0$ \\ \textbf{[\textit{°C}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{P}$_0$ \\ \textbf{[\textit{bar}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Acquisition} \\ \textbf{frequency} \\ \textbf{[\textit{kHz}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Number} \\ \textbf{images}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Chunk} \\ \textbf{frequency} \\ \textbf{[\textit{Hz}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{$\Delta$t} [\textit{$\mu$s}]} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Camera} \\ \textbf{resolution}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{1.00} & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 161.567 & 1048 x 1952  \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{2.00} & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 119.000 & 1048 x 1416  \\
    \hline
    \textbf{3.00} & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & 90 x 950 x 2 & 3 & 13.000 & 1048 x 1056 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{4.00} & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 975 x 2 & 4 & 16.567 & 1048 x 832  \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}          
\\[10pt]
\caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\label{table:3D_characterization_Data}
\end{table}



Welcome to TeX.SE.

Have a look at https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 If you don't use so many lines and colours, you will automatically avoid the problem.

If you don't want to follow samcarter's to make your table easier to understand, could you complete your example with the necessary packages and definitions (and documentclass) so that we can compile it?

in this column the header is smaller then the content of the cells, and \makecell seems to confuse colortbl. Use \begin{tabular}{@{}{c}}\textbf{Number} \\ \textbf{images}\end{tabular} instead of the \makecell command.

Your problem is not special related to Overleaf. It happen at all LaTeX installation.

Could you change the title of this question to something more concrete?

Note how the Number images column is the only one where the width of the header is narrower than the rest of the column entries (in row 2+). Easiest would be to write Number of image to expand the title just enough to remove the coloured cell anomaly.
For completeness, here's an updated table using booktabs and siunitx to format the columns.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry} % Just for this example

\colorlet{documentcolor}{blue!10}

\newcommand{\coltoprule}{%
  \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}% Set top rule (with no bottom gap)
  \arrayrulecolor{documentcolor}% Update array rule colour to match header
  \specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}% Add coloured rule
  \arrayrulecolor{black}% Reset array rule colour
}
\newcommand{\colmidrule}{%
  \arrayrulecolor{documentcolor}% Update array rule to match header
  \specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}% Add coloured rule
  \arrayrulecolor{black}% Reset array rule colour
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}% Add mid rule (with no top gap)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
      >{\bfseries}c % U [m/s]
      S[table-format = 7] % Re
      S[table-format = 2.1] % T_0 [°C]
      c % P_0 [bar]
      S[table-format = 1.2] % Acquisition frequency [kHz]
      c % Number of images
      c % Chunk frequency [Hz]
      S[table-format = 3.3] % Δ t [μs]
      >{\centering\arraybackslash}X % Camera resolution
    }
    \coltoprule    
    \rowcolor{documentcolor} % Header row
    \bfseries \makecell[b]{U \\ {}[$m/s$]} & 
      {\bfseries Re} & 
      {\bfseries \makecell[b]{$\mathbf{T}_0$ \\ {}[${}^\circ C$]}} & 
      \bfseries \makecell[b]{$\mathbf{P}_0$ \\{} [$\mathit{bar}$]} & 
      {\bfseries \makecell[b]{Acquisition \\ frequency \\ {}[$\mathit{kHz}$]}} & 
      \bfseries \makecell[b]{Number of \\ images} & 
      \bfseries \makecell[b]{Chunk \\ frequency \\ {}[$\mathit{Hz}$]} & 
      {\bfseries \makecell[b]{$\Delta \mathbf{t}$ [${\mu}s$]}} & 
      \bfseries \makecell[b]{Camera \\ resolution} \\ 
    \colmidrule
    1.00 & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & $90 \times 900 \times 2$ & 2 & 161.567 & $\num{1048} \times \num{1952}$            \\ 
    2.00 & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & $90 \times 900 \times 2$ & 2 & 119.000 & $\num{1048} \times \num{1416}$            \\
    3.00 & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & $90 \times 950 \times 2$ & 3 &  13.000 & $\num{1048} \times \num{1056}$            \\
    4.00 & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & $90 \times 975 \times 2$ & 4 &  16.567 & $\num{1048} \times \phantom{0}\num{832}$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}        
  \caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I think the X for the last column just makes it look odd (in the original as well).  I would recommend switching that out for c, and maybe tabular* if OP wants the full width.

@Teepeemm: This is true. I purposefully reverted to a landscape format in my example to make things fit within the text block width, which may exacerbate the width of the X-column. The OP can decide.


Please always provide MWE (Minimal working Example), a small but complete document, which in preamble contain only to your problem relevant information and which reproduce your problem.

Some off-topic comment:

According to SI institution units should be written with upright letters. This is supported by siunitx package.
Ordinary variables are usually written in italic.
Culprit of your problem is use of \makecell or \thead macro in columns headers. Colored are only part of cell to the end of text in them. To the end of columns (when contents in other rows are wider than contents in header column rows) are not colored:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \scriptsize % Reduced font size
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{6}{c|} X|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!40} % Header row
\thead{U \\ {[\unit{\meter\per\second}]}}
    &    \thead{Re} 
        &   \thead{$T_0$\\ {[\unit{\degreeCelsius}]}}
            &   \thead{Acquisition\\ frequency\\ {[\unit{\kilo\hertz}]}}
                &   \thead{Number\\ images}
                    &   \thead{$\Delta t$  {[\unit{\micro\second}]}} 
                        &   \thead{Camera\\ resolution}     \\ \\
    \hline
\textbf{1.00} & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 161.567 & 1048 x 1952    \\ 
    \hline
\textbf{2.00} & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 119.000 & 1048 x 1416    \\
    \hline
\textbf{3.00} & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & 90 x 950 x 2 & 3 & 13.000 & 1048 x 1056     \\
    \hline
\textbf{4.00} & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 975 x 2 & 4 & 16.567 & 1048 x 832      \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}          

\caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\label{table:3D_characterization_Data}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

Solution is not use \makecellin colored rows. For example, if you are willing to usetabularray` package, MWE which produce table with desired design, can be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}               % just for this example

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}             % <---
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  % <---
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}         % <---


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small % Reduced font size
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=7.0}]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=2.1}]
                        c
                        Q[c, si={table-format=2.1}]
                        X[c]
                        c
                        Q[c, si={table-format=3.3}]
                        X[c]},
             row{1} = {guard, bg={cyan!30}, font=\bfseries, b}
             }
% column headers
    \toprule
{U \\ {[\unit{\meter\per\second}]}}
    &   Re 
        &   {$T_0$\\ {[\unit{\degreeCelsius}]}}
            &   {$P_0$\\ {[\unit{\bar}]}}
                &   {Acquisition\\ frequency\\ {[\unit{\kilo\hertz}]}}
                    &   {Number\\ of images}
                        &   {Chunk\\ frequency\\ {[\unit{\hertz}]}}
                            &   {$\Delta t$\\  {[\unit{\micro\second}]}} 
                                &   {Camera\\ resolution}     \\
% table body
    \midrule
1.00    & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & \numproduct{90 x 900 x 2} & 2 & 161.567 & \numproduct{1048 x 1952}    \\ 
2.00    & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & \numproduct{90 x 900 x 2} & 2 & 119.000 & \numproduct{1048 x 1416}    \\
3.00    & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & \numproduct{90 x 950 x 2} & 3 &  13.000 & \numproduct{1048 x 1056}    \\
4.00    & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & \numproduct{90 x 975 x 2} & 4 &  16.567 & \numproduct{1048 x 832 }    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}          

\caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\label{table:3D_characterization_Data}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


As you can see, above table is a bit redesigned: removed are all vertical lines and horizontal lines in table body.

The package nicematrix has tools to address that kind of problem. In the following code, I have taken your example and replaced {tabularx} by {NiceTabularX} (provided by nicematrix) with the key color-inside (because of the command \rowcolor inside the tabular).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\scriptsize % Reduced font size
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|X|}[color-inside]
    \hline
    \rowcolor{cyan!30} % Header row
    \makecell{\textbf{U} \\ \textbf{[\textit{m}/\textit{s}]}} & 
    \textbf{Re} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{T}$_0$ \\ \textbf{[\textit{\textdegree C}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{P}$_0$ \\ \textbf{[\textit{bar}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Acquisition} \\ \textbf{frequency} \\ \textbf{[\textit{kHz}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Number} \\ \textbf{images}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Chunk} \\ \textbf{frequency} \\ \textbf{[\textit{Hz}]}} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{$\Delta$t} [\textit{$\mu$s}]} & 
    \makecell{\textbf{Camera} \\ \textbf{resolution}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{1.00} & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 161.567 & 1048 x 1952  \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{2.00} & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 900 x 2 & 2 & 119.000 & 1048 x 1416  \\
    \hline
    \textbf{3.00} & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & 90 x 950 x 2 & 3 & 13.000 & 1048 x 1056 \\
    \hline
    \textbf{4.00} & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & 90 x 975 x 2 & 4 & 16.567 & 1048 x 832  \\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabularX}          
\\[10pt]
\caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\label{table:3D_characterization_Data}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Here is the output:

Of course, it's possible to improve that tabular. Here is a suggestion which also uses nicematrix (and siunitx).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}             
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}           
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}       

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c
                    S[table-format=7.0]
                    S[table-format=2.1]
                    c
                    S[table-format=2.1]
                    X[c]
                    c
                    S[table-format=3.3]
                    X[c]}
% column headers
\toprule
\RowStyle[rowcolor=cyan!30,bold]{}
{U}
    & {Re} 
        & {$T_0$}
            & {$P_0$}
                & {\Block{}{Acquisition\\ frequency}}
                    & {\Block{}{Number\\ of images}}
                        &  {\Block{}{Chunk\\ frequency}}
                            & {$\Delta t$}
                                & {\Block{}{Camera\\ resolution}} \\
\RowStyle[rowcolor=cyan!30]{}
[m/s] & & [\unit{\degreeCelsius}] & [bar] & [kHz] & & [Hz] & [\unit{\micro\second}] \\
% table body
    \midrule
1.00    & 1000000 & 11.3 & 1 & 7.00 & \numproduct{90 x 900 x 2} & 2 & 161.567 & \numproduct{1048 x 1952}    \\ 
2.00    & 1000000 & 11.4 & 1 & 6.50 & \numproduct{90 x 900 x 2} & 2 & 119.000 & \numproduct{1048 x 1416}    \\
3.00    & 1000000 & 11.5 & 1 & 6.00 & \numproduct{90 x 950 x 2} & 3 &  13.000 & \numproduct{1048 x 1056}    \\
4.00    & 1000000 & 11.6 & 1 & 6.50 & \numproduct{90 x 975 x 2} & 4 &  16.567 & \numproduct{1048 x 832 }    \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}          

\caption{3D characterization: water tunnel, camera and laser data corresponding to each tested velocity}
\label{table:3D_characterization_Data}
\end{table}

\end{document}


